# Write an program that terminates after 60 seconds - Cops' Thread

Tags: cops-and-robbers

This is a cops and robbers challenge - [Robber's Thread](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/102074/48261)

Write a program that terminates after exactly 60 seconds (or as close to it as possible). For example:

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    sleep(60);
    return 0;
}
```

However, your goal is to write this program such that terminating after exactly 1 minute is essentially *inherent* to the program's execution - it should be difficult to change the program to predictably run for a different amount of time without overhauling the algorithm. The robbers will attempt to change your program such that it terminates after **31** seconds instead of 60, and they will have to do so with a solution whose [Levenshtein edit distance](http://planetcalc.com/1721/) is up to half of the length of your submission.

If you do not wish to take advantage of system interrupts or the system clock, you can use either of the following:

- The speed of printing to `stdout` is controlled by the baud rate of the terminal you are printing to. If you wish, you can control the speed of your program by printing to `stdout` with a set baud rate. However, you must also cite an actual piece of hardware or terminal program that has that baud rate as default (e.g. a serial printer with a default print speed of 300 baud).
- If you are working in a language where all operations take some constant amount of time (such as assembly language), you can control the speed of your program by specifying the processor's clock rate. However, this too must be accompanied with a citation of an actual processor chip that runs at that speed (e.g. the 1 MHz 6502 put inside Apple //e and NES boards).

This is cops and robbers, so prepare to rigorously defend your algorithm! If your solution has been cracked, put `[Cracked](link to cracker)` in your header. If your solution remains uncracked after exactly **2 weeks**, it is safe from future cracking attempts - put `Safe` in your header and explain how your algorithm works.

The winner of this challenge is the Safe solution with the most upvotes.

Comment: I believe this fits into the category of popcon "do [task] in a creative way" which is considered too broad by our community, so this might be closed. Seems like a cool challenge, though...

Comment: @Challenger5 maybe it could be turned into a police v robbers challenge, where the robbers are supposed to edit the program to terminate in 30 seconds for example. That is, if this would indeed be considered too broad.

Comment: Yeah, ditto to Jarko's idea, I feel like this might be a good challenge for `cops-and-robbers` - it doesn't need much changing, TBH.

Comment: *nigh impossible to change the program to predictably run for a different amount of time without completely rewriting it* isn't well-defined; the Jelly program `281ÆCœS` does exactly that, and making it wait for 30 seconds requires changing at least three characters.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question; questions without an objective validity criterion are off-topic, as they make it impossible to indisputably decide whether a submission is valid or not.

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam That sounds interesting... maybe the robbers had to rewrite the cop's program to terminate in 30 secs but with the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) from the original strictly less than some value.

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam That's a good idea. Glad to know that that category exists for just this sort of stuff.

Comment: @Dennis That is a good point. By "completely rewriting" I mean something around the lines of changing the algorithm itself substantially.

Comment: As before, *without overhauling the algorithm* isn't well-defined. In case you're not aware, we have a [sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2140/12012) where you can get  feedback from the community before posting your challenge on the main site.

Comment: @Dennis I was aware of the sandbox, though I was not aware of the "sort by active" capability on the answer list.

Comment: What if you can't reduce it to 31 seconds exactly? What happens then? Also, 2 weeks is a bit long - usually, a submission that's uncracked for 1 week is safe.

Comment: @Qwerp-Derp Not 31 seconds simply doesn't count. I'm saying 31 instead of 30 because it's much harder to go down 31/60 than it is to divide by 2. It doesn't have to be 31.0000..., though - no computer can be that accurate.

Comment: What would be accurate enough for 31 seconds? Is 31.01 seconds okay? Where's the "window" for an accurate time?

Comment: Am I allowed to create an expression (math expression maybe) that takes 60 seconds to evaluate on certain specs that I'd provide with the answer?

Comment: edit distance of half the length is too high, I think. It should be `max(3, log_2(#chars)+2)` or something like that.

Comment: @justhalf That's a good point. I was, however, thinking of a possible program that has `System.out.println();` over and over or something like that, with a fixed output rate. You would have to delete at least half of the characters to bring the termination time down to 31 seconds.

Comment: @TheHansinator: You can limit the program length also (but it might hurt for some languages like Unary, haha)

Comment: @justhalf - Actually, I just realized that my example (and probably the others like it) could be defeated with a simple `return`. I'll adjust the puzzle requirements soon...

Answer (score 6):

## Perl 52 bytes (26 edits allowed) (Safe, technically speaking)

```perl
sub a{[gmtime+time]->[0]^$x}$x=a;0 until a;0 while a
```

Unfortunately, I don't think it's possible to write an uncrackable Perl program (it should become obvious why if and when this is cracked; being able to edit half the program is just too much), but this algorithm should be very hard to change to wait for any length of time other than 1 minute.

Marking this as safe, as nobody's officially submitted a crack for 14 days (although someone unofficially cracked it by just writing a separate program and commenting out the existing code). The basic idea of the program is as follows: we look at the seconds digit of the time, loop until it changes, then loop until it returns to its original value. This requires quite some changes to alter to a length of time other than 1 minute, 1 hour, or 1 day (although 26 edits is easily enough – you can do some modular arithmetic on the seconds value to determine a new target to wait until – but nobody found that solution).

Comment: `sleep(31)#ime+time]->[0]^$x}$x=a;0 until a;0 while a` is what you meant, right? I'm not posting this as a solution hoping that someone will try to provide a "proper" solution. (I don't know perl, so I'm out)

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. The algorithm might be hard to change (although probably not impossible; I can see an approach that might work), but under the rules of the challenge you can just completely ignore it and write your own program to do the waiting.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 30 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/102160/12012)

```
69266249554160949116534784œSÆl
```

This can't be tested online since TIO has a 60 second timeout.

#### Verification

```
$ time jelly eun '69266249554160949116534784œSÆl'
69266249554160949116534784

real    1m0.033s
user    0m0.433s
sys     0m0.041s
```

#### How it works

The natural logarithm (`Æl`) of **69266249554160949116534784** is **59.5**. `œS` sleeps that many seconds before returning its left argument. Adding the wait time to the **500ms** boot time of Jelly (mostly spent loading SymPy and NumPy) gives an execution time of roughly one minute. This is on a third generation Core i7 CPU at 3.40 GHz and an SSD. The boot time will naturally vary on other computers.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/102160/62131).

Answer (score 0):

## [reticular](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/reticular), 11 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/102152/31957)

```
[[3w]5*]4*;
```

Running:

```
λ timecmd reticular test.ret
command took 0:1:0.38 (60.38s total)
```

([`timecmd` link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6209392/4119004))

### Explanation

```
[[3w]5*]4*;
[      ]4*  execute this 4 times
 [  ]5*     execute this 5 times
  3w        wait 3 seconds
          ; terminate program
```

Comment: Where can I find the documentation for / an implementation of this language?

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/102152/62131).

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth - 5 bytes (distance of 2 allowed) [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/102158/31343).

```
.d*T6
```

[Mess with it online](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.d%2aT6&debug=0) (though it times out with 60 seconds).

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/102158/12012) (for real this time)

Comment: @Dennis nice one