# Write an program that terminates after 60 seconds - Robbers Thread

Tags: cops-and-robbers

This is a cops and robbers challenge - [Cop's Thread](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/102056/48261)

Each of the cops have been tasked to write a program that terminates after exactly 60 seconds, or as close as possible. For example:

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    sleep(60);
    return 0;
}
```

Your goal is to take any of the uncracked submissions and change it so that it terminates after **31** seconds. If a cop's answer has been up for more than two weeks, it is immune to cracking. The original answer and your edit must have a [Levenshtein edit distance](http://planetcalc.com/1721/) of up to half of the original program's length.

The robber with the most cracks wins!

The cops have been allowed to do either of the following if they do not wish to use the system time calls:

- The speed of printing to `stdout` is controlled by the baud rate of the terminal you are printing to. If you wish, you can control the speed of your program by printing to `stdout` with a set baud rate. However, you must also cite an actual piece of hardware or terminal program that has that baud rate as default (e.g. a serial printer with a default print speed of 300 baud).
- If you are working in a language where all operations take some constant amount of time (such as assembly language), you can control the speed of your program by specifying the processor's clock rate. However, this too must be accompanied with a citation of an actual processor chip that runs at that speed (e.g. the 1 MHz 6502 put inside Apple //e and NES boards).

If you encounter a solution with this specification, you cannot change this parameter. (Not that it would help you much anyway, since it's hard to find an upgraded chip or serial output device with a 31:60 speed ratio).

Comment: Your pseudo-code definition of *fundamentally changing the algorithm* is a step in the right direction, but this part and the "reasonable" baud rates and CPU frequencies are still too vague. Also, neither the cops' nor the robbers' challenge have a winning criterion at this point, nor do they specify how a solution becomes safe.

Comment: @Dennis Would it help if I actually wrote a good answer and cracked it?

Comment: No. Validity and winning criteria have to be objective. Having an example of a "good answer" doesn't hurt, but it also doesn't replace a proper specification.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/102157/62131), edit distance 5 from 30 bytes

Original:

```
69266249554160949116534784œSÆl
```

Crack:

```
69266249554160949116534784œSÆl_29$$
```

I just subtracted 29 from the timeout immediately before the `œS` runs. (`_29` subtracts 29, the dollars control precedence, a bit like parentheses in other languages.)

Answer (score 1):

## [reticular](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/102151/62131), edit distance 4 from 11 bytes

Original:

```
[[3w]5*]4*;
```

Crack:

```
6w[[1w]5*]5*;
```

The edit distance we've been given is just way too high to make cracking difficult. There was a lot of freedom in this one, so I aimed for one that preserved the spirit of the original code.

## [reticular](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/102151/62131), edit distance 3 from 11 bytes

I found an improved crack, here it is:

Original:

```
[[3w]5*]4*;
```

Crack:

```
1w[[3w]5*]2*;
```

Comment: Hm, nice. I do think the edit distance is too high as well.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth, 5 bytes, Maltysen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/102154/12012)

```
.dh*T3
```

`*T3` computes **30**, `h` increments, and `.d` waits for that many seconds.